# How to do regular expressions with all lines

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

There is a text like this (many lines)

`ABCD
TEST(aa
  bb
  cc
  dd)
EFG`

i want

`"TEST(aa 
bb
cc
dd)"`

but

`TEST\(.*\)` =>

`"TEST(aa"`

How can I get results that include all the lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After `TEST(`, try selecting characters other than `)` until you come to a `)`. By default, `.` does not match a newline, but an excluded character set *will*.

```
TEST\([^)]*\)
```

https://regex101.com/r/454Kvg/1

Answer (score 0):

The [dot](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) does not match line break characters. You could use a [modifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) `(?s)` to make the dot match line breaks.

The `.*` should then be non greedy `.*?` to match the first closing `)`

[`(?s)TEST\(.*?\)`](https://regex101.com/r/H5UMBd/1)